# I am trying to get balance of CAKE token in my wallet, but it gives me an "invalid address" error

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, web3.py, pancakeswap

I am trying to get CAKE Balance in BSC.

```
const tokenabi =
   [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "balance",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
]; 

const tokencontract = new w.eth.Contract(tokenabi, "0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82");

const checkBalance = (amount) => { 
    tokencontract.methods.balanceOf(wallet.Address)
  .call().then(function (b) {
        let balance = Web3.utils.fromWei(b, 'ether') 
        if (balance < parseFloat(amount)) {
            console.log("You don't have enough balance :", amount, "CAKE", "|", "Actual Balance:", balance, "CAKE")
        } else {
            console.log(`Your balance is enough: ${balance} CAKE`)
        }
    })
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> ERROR: 'invalid address (argument="address", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0)',
> code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
> argument: '_owner',
> value: undefined

Comment: Check if wallet.Address is valorized when you pass it to the function `balanceOf()`

Comment: Lol. Thanks bro. That fixed it for me.